# Obtener ID del elemento clickeado (seleccionado)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un modal con distintos *tabs* y necesito cargar el id que he clickeado para consultar unos registros en directorio.

Con este código voy mostrando contenido en distintos *tabs*. Pero ¿Cómo cargar esos id en la función?

Los id vienen de distintos div en mi *HTML*.

Por ejemplo tengo *div* así:

```
<div id="l73" >Textos </div>
<div id="l74" >Textos </div>
<div id="l75" >Textos </div>
<div id="l76" >Textos </div>
```

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#l73").click(function() {
                $("#home").html('<embed src="./files/l73_4b/l73_ejemplo.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" /> ');
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
          $("#l73").click(function() {
              $("#profile").html('<embed src="./files/l73_4b/l73_instruccion.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" style="margin-top: -420px;"  /> ');
          });
      });
  </script>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
          $("#l73").click(function() {
              $("#contact").html('<embed src="./files/l73_4b/l73_instruccion.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" style="margin-top: -420px;"  /> ');
          });
      });
  </script>
</div>
```

Lo que busco es que al darle click al *div* con id 73 por ejemplo, ese id se cargue en la función `$("**#l73**").click` y ver como cargarlo aquí `<embed src="./files/**l73_4b**/l73_instruccion.pdf"` para que me consulte en esta ruta.

Comment: En todas tus funciones estás asignando el evento al mismo elemento `#173` y, en cada clic, va a ejecutarlas todas. Deberías crear los elementos de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/) para asegurar que se vea como esperas y, después, aplicar los eventos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que usas jQuery, te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo usando esta librería

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.clickable').click(function() {
        $('#home').html('<embed src="./files/'+this.id+'_4b/'+this.id+'_ejemplo.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" />')
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="l73" class="clickable">Textos </div>
<div id="l74" class="clickable">Textos </div>
<div id="l75" class="clickable">Textos </div>
<div id="l76" class="clickable">Textos </div>

<div id="home"></div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Simple y efectiva, ¡muy buena respuesta!

Answer (score 5):

Se puede solucionar de una forma sencilla, usando los eventos, vas a tener que colocar una misma clase a todos los `<div>`, pues así nos evitamos añadir un *eventListener* por cada uno

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".click").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado el id "+id);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="l73" class="click">Textos </div>
<div id="l74" class="click">Textos </div>
<div id="l75" class="click">Textos </div>
<div id="l76" class="click">Textos </div>
```

Usamos `.target` para saber a cual elemento se ha clickeado

Teniendo ya el elemento, solo usamos `getAttribute` para poder obtener el `id`

Entonces, solo que da ponerle un ID al `<embed>`

Usamos [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para obtener todos los elementos del DOM con un selector de CSS Específico, los cuales podremos recorrer con [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".click").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    const process = "./files/"+id+"/"+id+"_instruccion.pdf";
    emb.setAttribute("src", process);
    console.log("ID Procesado: "+emb.getAttribute("src"));
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="l73" class="click">Textos </div>
<div id="l74" class="click">Textos </div>
<div id="l75" class="click">Textos </div>
<div id="l76" class="click">Textos </div>
<embed id="emb">
```

Answer (score -1):

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll(".click").forEach(el => {

  el.addEventListener("click", e => {

    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");

    console.log("Se ha clickeado el id "+id);

  });

});
```

Comment: amigo en ese codigo que son el "el" que colocas en forEach y el "e".
No entendi soy nuevo en esto, el codigo funciona bien pero me gustaria saber como.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).